# Exclude weekends from my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, getdate, datepart

I have a query which is working fine.
The query basically retrieves data between 6-8 days old from current date. I'd like exclude the weekends when measuring the age of the data.

Example: If a record is registered Friday, then Monday morning it will show like it's 4 days old, but it's actually only 2 days old, because Satuday and Sunday shouldn't count.

I tried this, which does not seem to be working:

```
Select id, name, CreatedDate
from table
where 
CreatedDate <= DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE()) AND CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE()) -- here I get data between 6-8 days old
 AND ((DATEPART(dw, CreatedDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) -- Here im trying to exclude weekends
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see calendar and try this query

```
// Logic is very simple. 
// See calendar and try.
// If today is Monday, then Prev8workingdays will include 
// 8 working days + 2 weekends = 12 days. 
// Then result will be dateadd(day,-12, getdate()) = 12 days before today.
// Same logic for other days week
DECLARE @Prev8workingdays date = CASE
    WHEN datepart(dw, getdate()) IN (2,3,4) THEN dateadd(day,-12, getdate()) 
    WHEN datepart(dw, getdate()) IN (1) THEN dateadd(day,-11, getdate()) 
    ELSE dateadd(day,-10, getdate())
    END
DECLARE @Pre6WorkingDay date = CASE
        WHEN datepart(dw, getdate()) IN (2) THEN dateadd(day,-10, getdate()) 
        WHEN datepart(dw, getdate()) IN (1) THEN dateadd(day,-9, getdate()) 
        ELSE dateadd(day,-8, getdate())
    END

SELECT sd.* FROM
@SampleDate sd
WHERE sd.CreatedDate >= @Prev8workingdays AND sd.CreatedDate <= @Pre6WorkingDay
```

Reference link [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

Comment: Hi, I just tried this. So basically this would measure the age of a record without taking weekends into account?

Can you explain what the dateadd(day,-12) and (-11) does? What if i want to measure rpevious 5 days?

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
     WHERE DATEPART(dw, date_created) NOT IN (1, 7);
```

Comment: This will work, assuming DATEFIRST = 7. Also, i would just say weekday instead of dw for clarity.

Comment: Would this measure the age of data without counting the weekends in the measurement?

Comment: No this is a replacement for AND ((DATEPART(dw, CreatedDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select id, name, CreatedDate
from table
where CreatedDate < GETDATE()-6 and CreatedDate > GETDATE()-8 and
((DATEPART(dw, CreatedDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

Comment: Would this measure the age of data without counting the weekends in the measurement?